# Library for CDK Resource Type constant strings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Is there any library in CDK where we can reference resource type constants? For example, the strings `AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm` or `AWS::Lambda::Function`. I'm using these as inputs to CDK test functions like [hasResourceProperties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.assertions.Template.html#haswbrresourcetype-props) and preferably have this parameter with autocomplete suggestions rather than typing out the string every time.

The closest I found was [ResourceType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_config.ResourceType.html) in the aws_config package but unfortunately I couldn't find a way to convert these instances into strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it - it is indeed `ResourceType`. To access the actual CloudFormation resource type as a string, just use the [`complianceResourceType`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_config.ResourceType.html#complianceresourcetype) prop.

```js
// 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
const resoureTypeStr = ResourceType.EC2_INSTANCE.complianceResourceType;
```